# Mongo DB aggregation date filter not working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, etl, data-analysis

I am trying to filter date on MongoDB via pymongo. Specifically looking to "match" all dates greater than a given date.  My query is definitely correct, as it queries perfectly in MongoDB compass - aggregations. However once I add this to my pymongo code it returns zero results. So as mentioned it did not work, so I have confirmed via the compass application, that my query string is infact correct, please assist, my code below is what I used to query in compass which works, and further below is my full aggregate pipeine in pymongo - which doesn't work. ( BTW : My date format is stored correctly in mongo - as "date")

```
{
// MongoDB compass code - works fine.

"date": {"$gt": new Date("2020-12-06T00:00:00.000+00:00")}

}
```

```
//Pymongo code

betdate = weekcol.aggregate([
    ## stage 1
    {"$match":{
  
"date": {"$gt": new Date("2020-12-06T00:00:00.000+00:00")}

    }        }
        
])

for bdate in betdate:
    print(bdate)
```

The above pymongo code, throws me the error :

File "", line 9
"date": {"$gt": new Date("2020-12-06T00:00:00.000+00:00")}
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I had a feeling it was the new date() which was a problem, but I changed it to ISODate(), and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `ISODate("2020-12-06T00:00:00Z")`

Comment: @Yahya , I have tried that.....I have took your advise and added the date with the "z" and the end but it still doesnt work

Comment: `new Date()` is Javascript code but you are in python. I think you have to use the python `datetime` object. `ISODate` is just an alias for `new Date()` in the mongo shell which you don't use either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent in pymongo is:

```
import datetime
import pytz

filter1 = {"date": {"$gt": datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)}}
```

Comment: @ Belly Buster, Thanks alot it works now.  It returns the date back in comma separated Y-M-D.....But I should be able to work my way and compile it back into a date-string. Thanks again for your reply and help

Comment: It returns a datetime object which you can easily convert to a string in virtually any format using `strftime()`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior